# PowerApps Form and Nuances of Editing a List

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, powerapp

I've been using SharePoint Online and following Shane Young on creating lookups in PowerApps using a dropdown listbox. Everything works fine. When I go back to my list and choose 'EDIT' at the top or click the 3-dots > EDIT, it works great! My lookup pulls from a secondary list column.

However, if I double-click the item, which normally is an alternative method of editing an item, my listBox shows up. It displays the item that would-otherwise-be-the-first-item-in-the-list (even though this value is incorrect) and it does not display a dropdown icon for me to choose another value.

It's as if the double-click-edit form is a different form than the manual-edit form. What gives? Anyone else have this problem? Any way to make both edit experiences the same?

Comment: Have you asked Shane about this? He's active on Twitter.